# How to get an accurate file list through the google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm developing an application using the Google drive api (`java` version).  The application saves files on a Google drive mimicking a file system (i.e. has a folder tree).  I started by using the files.list() method to retrieve all the existing files on the Google drive but the response got slower as the number of files increased (after a couple of hundred).

The java Google API hardcodes the response timeout to 20 seconds.  I changed the code to load one folder at a time recursively instead (using `files.list().setQ("'folderId' in parents)` ).  This method beats the timeout problem but it consistently misses about 2% of the files in my folders (the same files are missing each time).  I can see those files through the Google drive web browser interface and even through the Google drive API if I search the file name directly `files.list().setQ("title='filename'")`.

I'm assuming that the "in parents" search uses some inexact indexing which may only be updated periodically.  I need a file listing that's more robust and accurate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear - I always call setMaxResults( 100000 ) so it is not that I'm hitting the default 100 limit.

Comment: I upvoted this because I'm working on a browser less device with gdrive. I'm currently storing the list locally in a json file. I use that to poll for updates/changes, because I ran through the exact issue you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you utilize the Page mechanism to do multiple times of queries and each query just asks for a small mount of result ?

Comment: I think this was the problem I had, I've since updated to the newest api and everything is fine.